# SQL: How to get in a single query info from a table and aggregate info from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server 2014 on Windows7.
I have a table named "*PollingStatus*".
The below query :

```
SELECT DeviceIP
      ,ServiceStatus
      ,ReportedErrors
FROM PollingStatus
```

...gives some info like this:

```
DeviceIP   |    ServiceStatus   |   ReportedErrors   
10.20.1.1  |          0         |         0     
10.20.1.2  |          0         |         0
```

And in another table named "*DeviceProperties*" I have something like:

```
DeviceIP   |    DeviceType      |    SwVersion   
10.20.1.1  |          3         |       800     
10.20.1.1  |          2         |       802     
10.20.1.1  |          1         |       804     
10.20.1.2  |          2         |       800     
10.20.1.2  |          3         |       801     
10.20.1.2  |          2         |       806
```

What I would need is a query to get something like this:

```
DeviceIP   |  ServiceStatus  |  ReportedErrors  | DeviceType | SwVersion  
10.20.1.1  |        0        |        0         |    1       |   804  
10.20.1.2  |        0        |        0         |    2       |   806
```

i.e.: compared with my existing query, I would like to have also the DeviceType and  the **maximum** `SwVersion` of the device, from the second table "*DeviceProperties*".

Comment: Hint: join + group by or join + subquery + group by

Comment: Seems like a pretty basic query quite honestly. What have you tried? What research have you done? Unless I'm misunderstanding, you just need a `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY`...

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice

```
SELECT DeviceIP
  ,ServiceStatus
  ,ReportedErrors
  ,Max(SwVersion) as MaxSwVersion
FROM PollingStatus p
      INNER JOIN DeviceProperties d
            ON p.DeviceIP = d.DeviceIP
GROUP BY DeviceIP, ServiceStatus, ReportedErrors
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
D.DeviceIP,
D.ReportedErrors,
D.ServiceStatus,
DD.DeviceType,
DD.SwVersion 
from @Device D
INNER JOIN (Select 
                DeviceIP,
                MIN(DeviceType)DeviceType,
                MAX(SwVersion)SwVersion 
                        from  @Devicetype
GROUP BY DeviceIP )DD
ON D.DeviceIP = DD.DeviceIP
```

Comment: Seems close to what I need. But I am afraid it won't get the DeviceType related to maximum SwVersion, but the maximum of DeviceType, if I'm not mistaken.  (normally device type doesn't change, but yet it is possible).

Comment: can you please explain me clearly so that I can try from my side to give better solution@groenhen

Comment: Yes, I have updated the example in the question, I guess it is much more meaningful than my explanation.  The idea is I am afraid not to get the max value for DeviceType each time (3 in the above example), instead of 1 for SwVersion 804 and 2 for SwVersion 806..

Comment: @groenhen I have updated the answer MIN(Devicetype) it gives required result .please check

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
    SELECT 
        ps.DeviceIp, 
        ps.ServiceStatus, 
        ps.ReportedErrors, 
        dp.DeviceType, 
        Max(dp.SwVersion)
    FROM PollingStatus ps
    INNER JOIN DeviceProperties dp ON dp.DeviceIp = ps.DeviceIp
    GROUP BY ps.DeviceIp, ps.ServiceStatus, ps.ReportedErrors, dp.DeviceType;
```

Other than that, use a different type of join if you expect records in one table have no correspondent in the other.